# How to see if integer has a specific digit in it in C

Tags: c

I need to build a program, that would write all numbers from 0 to 100, but will place an * instead of any number that contains the digit 3 or can be divided by 3. This is what I have so far. How can I make it work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  int i, c;
  c = 100;
  for (i = 0; i <= c; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
      printf("*");
    }
    if (i)
      printf("%d\n", i);
  }
}
```

Comment: you are quite close, try using an `else` to make sure you don't print both (https://duckduckgo.com/?q=if+else+c&ia=web)

Comment: For contains 3, that is best done in a separate function where you keep dividing by 10 until zero, looking if the remainder was 3.

Comment: I fixed your code indentation and empty lines for you. No problem! But: **Your code editor should have done this for you!** A **lot** of the problems we see beginners having is things like missed `{` or wrong logic, and these get very easy to spot once you format your code using the tools of your editor. Really, do that, and your life will become much nicer :)

Comment: Let me quickly note a few problems with your code:
**1.** `main()` misses its return type specified, should be `int main()`.

Comment: **2.** this is C how you'd have written it 1981, not in 2021. You don't *have* to declare all variables at the beginning of the function anymore. In fact, here, it's a bit awkward. I think a `int c = 100;`, followed by `for(int i = 0; i <= c; i++){` would be better, because now the `i` exists only locally inside the `for`-loop, and you can make a new variable with the same name later on if you want to.

Comment: **3.** You use `if ( i %...) { printf("*"); }`. That's beautiful! Be consistent, use `{` `}` around the other `if` clause as well. Consistent code is easier to read and "scan" for errors :)

Comment: For future posts, always explain what the current/wrong results are so we don't all have to run your code to find out.

Answer (score 2):

> place an * instead of any number that contains the digit 3 or can be divided by 3.

OP's code took care of the "can be divided by 3" with `i % 3 == 0`.

How about a little [divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm) for the "contains the digit 3"?  Put a function in there.

```
if (contains_the_digit(i, 3) || (i % 3 == 0)) {
  printf("*\n");
} else {
  printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Now what is left is to define `contains_the_digit(int i, int digit)`

Mathematically (nice and efficient):

```
bool contains_the_digit_via_math(int i, int digit) {
  do {
    if (abs(i % 10) == digit) { // Look at the least digit, abs() to handle negative `i`
      return true;
    }
    i /= 10; // Now look at the upper decimal digits
  } while (i);  
  return false;
}
```

Or textually:

```
bool contains_the_digit_via_string(int i, int digit) {
  char buf[30];  // Something certainly big enough
  sprintf(buf, "%d", i);
  return strchr(buf, digit + '0') != NULL; 
}
```

Or use your imagination for other ideas.

---

- The key is to take your problems and reduce them to smaller ones with helper functions: *divide and conquer*.

Comment: suggestion: `contains_the_digit_via_math` should invoke `if (i < 0) {i = -i;}` so that it works as expected with negative numbers.  (In the OP's case, he's always passing non-negative numbers).

Comment: @selbie `if (i < 0) {i = -i;}` invokes _undefined behavior_ when `i == INT_MIN` and best to avoid.  Various ways to to handle your _negative number_ concern.  Post updated.

Comment: Very good point! I thought about that as I was typing.  I like the `abs` workaround.

Comment: @selbie A tighter solution is `if (i > 0) {i = -i;}` (use the negative side), then change loop to `if (-(i % 10) == digit)`. Likely a tad faster, but a bit more of "what?"

Answer (score 0):

1. Concert the number to a string
2. Replace '3' with '*' within that string

i.e.

```
int to_be_converted =12345612343242432; // Or summat else
char num[100]; // Should be more than enough
sprintf(num, "%d", to_be_converted);

for (int i =0; num[i]; i++) {
   if (num[i] -- '3') num[i] = '*';
}
printf("Here you go %s", num);
```

That should do the trick

Just ad the bit to go through the numbers and check if divisible by 3. I leave that to the reader.

Answer (score -1):

Seeing you forgot to add the return type `int` to your `int main()`, I think this is a good time to learn to write your own function!

In this case, you want a function that can check whether the last digit of a number is a `3` when you represent that number as base-10. That's easy! The function should look like (you need to `#include <stdbool.h>` at the beginning of your file, too):

```
bool ends_in_decimal_3(int number) {
  // figure out a way to find the difference 
  // between number, rounded to multiples of 10
  // and the original number. If that difference==3, 
  // then this ends in 3 and you can `return true;`
}
```

Armed with that function, you can see whether your `i` itself ends in `3`, or whether `i/10` ends in `3` and so on. Remembering that division `/` in C between `int`s always rounds down is a good trick to do that, and also an important hint on how to implement your rounding in `ends_in_decimal_3`.